# Why is the Cos function in C# giving me wrong answers?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math-functions

I have a method, in which I am using the Cos() Function from the namespace "Mathf".
Sadly, when I give, for example the in put of *45* it returns *0,52532*, which is wrong. Using a calculator I get the correct answer of *6.283185* Radians.

```
float angle = 45;
Debug.Log(Mathf.Cos(angle));
```

Prints out:

```
0,525322
```

Can anyone help me out here? I am very confused right now

Comment: It doesn't take degrees, but radians

Comment: From [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Cos.html): `The input angle, in radians.`

Comment: Cos gives a dimensionless value between -1 and +1, never 6 and never "radiants"

Comment: The *first* step when you get unexpected results is to check your expectations - which means to (re)read the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert to radians.

```
float angle = 45;
Debug.Log(Mathf.Cos(angle * Math.PI / 180.0f));
```